# Portable C++ 03 Exact Width Types

Tags: c++, types, portability, fixed-width

### Background

---

Unfortunately the current C++ standard lacks C99's exact-width types defined in the `stdint` header.

The next best thing I could find (in terms of portability) was `Boost`'s `cstdint.hpp` implementation from the `Boost.Integer` library.

### Concerns

---

That said, I've got a few problems with it:

`Boost`'s implementation dumps all the `typedef`s in the `boost namesapce` (instead of something like `boost::stdint`). This is totally ugly, because now you're either forced to use a `using`-directive only on the types that you're interested in (this is an extra maintenance chore), or bring the entire `boost namespace` into global¹ scope (this defeats the point of `namespace`s). I could, of course, be verbose and type `boost::uint32_t` everywhere, for example, but this isn't very future-friendly², either.

### Questions

---

I'm basically looking for advice. What's the best way to go about utilizing these not-yet-standard (not in C++ '03, anyway) types as transparently as possible?

For those of you who use this header, or rolled your own, how do you use these types? Blindly merge the `boost namespace` into the global `namespace`, prefix everything with "`boost::`", wrote a header that wraps `Boost.Integer`'s `cstdint.hpp`, etc.?

Any advice is appreciated.

Finally, having said all that (this wasn't a rant, by the way), I'm writing math-intensive code, so width-guarantees are important to me.

### Clarifications

---

1 - Global scope is my only option when I'm writing functions / `class` `template`s that take these types as arguments.

2 - When the next iteration of the standard wraps `stdint.h` into `cstdint`, I'll be stuck with a bunch of code that's prefixed with "`boost::`". This, then, will be an extra dependency (i.e., "boost/cstdint.hpp") that will be totally useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use stdint.h, and provide one for compilers that don't have it (e.g. for MSVC - [msinttypes](http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/)). Or write cstdint that is `using` all of Boost's typedefs (it's a write-once, so I don't think maintenance will be problematic).

It's easy to generate, too. Using [this little script](http://codepad.org/EtlJaUI3), i got that. You could also add defines to check for `int64`.

```
#ifndef GEN_CSTDINT
#define GEN_CSTDINT

#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>

using boost::int16_t;
using boost::int32_t;
using boost::int64_t;
using boost::int8_t;
using boost::int_fast16_t;
using boost::int_fast32_t;
using boost::int_fast64_t;
using boost::int_fast8_t;
using boost::int_least16_t;
using boost::int_least32_t;
using boost::int_least64_t;
using boost::int_least8_t;
using boost::intmax_t;
using boost::uint16_t;
using boost::uint32_t;
using boost::uint64_t;
using boost::uint8_t;
using boost::uint_fast16_t;
using boost::uint_fast32_t;
using boost::uint_fast64_t;
using boost::uint_fast8_t;
using boost::uint_least16_t;
using boost::uint_least32_t;
using boost::uint_least64_t;
using boost::uint_least8_t;
using boost::uintmax_t;

#endif // GEN_CSTDINT
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [portable version of stdint](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/pstdint.h).