# Boost's "cstdint" Usage

Tags: c++, boost, wrapper, cstdint

Boost's C99 stdint implementation is awfully handy. One thing bugs me, though. They dump all of their typedefs into the `boost namespace`. This leaves me with three choices when using this facility:

1. Use "`using namespace boost`"
2. Use "`using boost::[u]<type><width>_t`"
3. Explicitly refer to the target type with the `boost::` prefix; e.g., `boost::uint32_t foo = 0;`

---

- Option № 1 kind of defeats the point of namespaces. Even if used within local scope (e.g., within a function), things like function arguments still have to be prefixed like option № 3.
- Option № 2 is better, but there are a bunch of these types, so it can get noisy.
- Option № 3 adds an extreme level of noise; the `boost::` prefix is often ≥ to the length of the type in question.

---

My question is: What would be the most elegant way to bring all of these types into the global namespace? Should I just write a wrapper around `boost/cstdint.hpp` that utilizes option № 2 and be done with it?

---

Also, wrapping the header like so didn't work on VC++ 10 (problems with standard library headers):

```
namespace Foo
{
  #include <boost/cstdint.hpp>

  namespace boost_alias = boost;
}

using namespace Foo::boost_alias;
```

---

EDIT: I guess another option is to use the preprocessor to make it work on VC 10? Taking the snippet above:

```
#ifndef FOO_HPP_INCLUDED
#define FOO_HPP_INCLUDED

#if _MSC_VER >= 1600 /*VC++ 10*/ || defined USE_NATIVE_STDINT_HEADER
  #include <stdint.h>
#else
  namespace cstdint_wrapper
  {
    #include <boost/cstdint.hpp>

    namespace boost_alias = boost;
  }

  using namespace cstdint_wrapper::boost_alias;
#endif

#endif
```

Less work, I guess?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481733/portable-c-03-exact-width-types

Comment: Why do you need *all* of these types? I often use one or two of them, but I can't recall ever needing all of them.

Comment: @jalf: Good point. The truth is that I really don't want to have to manually synchronize my using-statements with the types that I actually use in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just use C99's `stdint.h` (it's actually now in VS 2010). For the versions of Visual C/C++ that don't include it, I use a public domain version from MinGW that I modified to work with VC6 (from when I had to work in VC6):

- http://snipplr.com/view/18199/stdinth/

There are a couple other options you might consider in this SO question: [C99 stdint.h header and MS Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio)

If you'd like to continue using `boost/cstdint.hpp`, I'd say that the suggestion of implementing a wrapper header that brings the types into the global namespace would be the way to go.

Does `boost/cstdint.hpp` provide anything I should know about that isn't in `stdint.h`?

Comment: Re: cstdint.hpp vs stdint.h -- I think they only difference is that cstdint.hpp may or may not include the 64-bit types and associated macros because long long is not yet standard. Other than that, I wanted to use boost's version because I already have several boost dependencies in my project. Didn't make sense to distribute an extra header in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea of writing a wrapper header that implements option 2 is definitely the better of those three options.

What I'd suggest, though, is a slight variant: Put those `using` declarations within another namespace, such as `cstdint` or something; then, you have the option if putting `using cstdint;` in your own code or explicitly specifying `cstdint::` on the particular uses.

Answer (score 2):

If you included directly the file  you will be forced to prefix it with std::. So the question is, which option would you take in this case. What would you do with the other types introduced by Boost? Would you prefix them with boost:: or not?

The fist one is clearly a bad option. 
You can implement option two using your my_cstdint.hpp file

```
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>

using boost::uint32_t;
...
```

and include my_cstdint.hpp in your application. But in my opinion it is a bad idea to add new symbols on the root namespace, you can get more conflicts as the types can be already defined by for example the stdint.h C file.

Even if the third option use a lot of characters, namespaces are there for this purpose. boost::uint32_t will be defined to the correct type depending on your toolset, so just use it, as you would use std::uint32_t.

Comment: But you can do this and add the using declarations to your project's namespace instead of the root.  (Everyone does use a project-specific namespace, right?  If you don't, you probably don't care about polluting the root namespace anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

I personally always use option 3. If things are too long, then you can use typedefs to reduce the amount of code.